# The graph making tool interprets my data... weirdly

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have sheet from which I attempt to import some data to a graph:

[image]
[image]
However, as you can see, the x-axis labels are not imported either as text nor as dates, but with the first two ciphers correct, and then "yy" instead of the year. The x-axis labels are displayed with "yy" in the chart as well.

Can anyone tell me what could possibly be the issue here?

Comment: Please check if the number format for X-axis is correct.

Comment: @lee Thanks, having a closer look at that seems to have fixed the issue

Comment: :D Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has to do with different abbreviations being used for numberformats in different locales. It appears that while the numberformat `dd.mm.yy` was valid for range-objects, when I tried to use that range as the sourcedata for the x-axis of my chart, the numberformat got carried over where `yy` was not a valid abbreviation for the numbers in the chart. Because of this, it was interpreted as a string and displayed as such.

One quick fix I found was closing and opening the workbook again, which often fixed the interpretation of the numberformat.

Alternately one can go to `format axis > axis options > number > type` and set it to the desired format:
[image]

If you are generating your charts using vba-code, I found that adding the line

```
WorkSheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yy"
```

after the data has been added to the chart, fixed the problem just fine as well (go figure).